# copy google sheet into specific folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to copy a google sheet and rename it and then save it into a specific folder. I can copy the sheet and rename it but it gets saved into the root folder instead of the specific folder.

```
var copySheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ABC123');
  copySheet.copy('aaa');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var copySheet = DriveApp.getFileById('ABC123'); // Original file
var destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('XYZ987'); // Destination folder
copySheet.makeCopy(destinationFolder);
```

See [ref docs here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app). Specifically [makeCopy(destination)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#makeCopy(Folder)).